# "All rights reserved" vs Creative Commons BY-NC-ND

Tags: copyright, legal-issues, creative-commons

When choosing a license for a paper, is the most restrictive creative commons [(CC Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivs (CC BY-NC-ND))](http://mirrors.creativecommons.org/presskit/icons/by.png) **equivalent** to "all rights reserved"? I'm having trouble understanding the specific differences since they both seem to offer the same "protection" (as far as I can tell).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing and not about academia. It **may** be on-topic on [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: As a sidenote, [“all rights reserved” has no legal impact](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_rights_reserved).

Comment: Academia does seem like the **most** appropriate community, especially considering the number of other CC questions here.

Comment: @Isius: But those questions are related to licensing academic content. In your question, there is no such relation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is the intention of the wording "all rights reserved"? If it serves to indicate that the work should not be reproduced without permission then it is clearly distinct from CC BY-NC-ND as this licence allows unrestricted non-commercial distribution of the work provided it is not modified